How to visualize CNN architecture using draw_convet?
I need to visualize the CNN model. The example is in the comments.
I've tried to use draw_convet (https://github.com/gwding/draw_convnet) but it keeps throwing a list of errors. Could you please help? Here's the model code itself:
model = nn.Sequential()
model.add_module('conv1', nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=32, kernel_size=2, padding=1)) 
model.add_module('relu1', nn.ReLU()) 
model.add_module('pool1', nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2))  
model.add_module('dropout1', nn.Dropout(p=0.4))

model.add_module('conv2', nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=2, padding=1))
model.add_module('relu2', nn.ReLU())        
model.add_module('pool2', nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2))   
model.add_module('dropout2', nn.Dropout(p=0.4))

model.add_module('conv3', nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=2, padding=1))
model.add_module('relu3', nn.ReLU())        
model.add_module('pool3', nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2))
model.add_module('dropout3', nn.Dropout(p=0.4))

model.add_module('conv4', nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=256, kernel_size=2, padding=1))
model.add_module('relu4', nn.ReLU()) 


model.add_module('conv5', nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=512, kernel_size=2, padding=1))
model.add_module('relu5', nn.ReLU())

model.add_module('pool4', nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=8)) 
model.add_module('flatten', nn.Flatten())  

model.add_module('fc', nn.Linear(512, 1))  
model.add_module('sigmoid', nn.Sigmoid())   

The list of errors I've got is the following:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 159
    156 text_list = ['Convolution', 'Max-pooling', 'Convolution', 'Max-pooling', 'Convolution']
    158 for ind in range(len(patch_size_list)):
--> 159     add_mapping(
    160         patches, colors, start_ratio_list[ind], end_ratio_list[ind],
    161         patch_size_list[ind], ind,
    162         top_left_list, loc_diff_list, num_show_list, size_list)
    163     label(top_left_list[ind], text_list[ind] + '\n{}x{} kernel'.format(
    164         patch_size_list[ind][0], patch_size_list[ind][1]), xy_off=[26, -65]
    165     )
    168 ############################
    169 # fully connected layers

Cell In[1], line 83, in add_mapping(patches, colors, start_ratio, end_ratio, patch_size, ind_bgn, top_left_list, loc_diff_list, num_show_list, size_list)
     71 def add_mapping(patches, colors, start_ratio, end_ratio, patch_size, ind_bgn,
     72                 top_left_list, loc_diff_list, num_show_list, size_list):
     74     start_loc = top_left_list[ind_bgn] \
     75         + (num_show_list[ind_bgn] - 1) * np.array(loc_diff_list[ind_bgn]) \
     76         + np.array([start_ratio[0] * (size_list[ind_bgn][1] - patch_size[1]),
     77                     - start_ratio[1] * (size_list[ind_bgn][0] - patch_size[0])]
     78                    )
---> 83     end_loc = top_left_list[ind_bgn + 1] \
     84         + (num_show_list[ind_bgn + 1] - 1) * np.array(
     85             loc_diff_list[ind_bgn + 1]) \
     86         + np.array([end_ratio[0] * size_list[ind_bgn + 1][1],
     87                     - end_ratio[1] * size_list[ind_bgn + 1][0]])
     90     patches.append(Rectangle(start_loc, patch_size[1], -patch_size[0]))
     91     colors.append(Dark)

IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py:340, in BaseFormatter.__call__(self, obj)
    338     pass
    339 else:
--> 340     return printer(obj)
    341 # Finally look for special method names
    342 method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

File c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py:152, in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, base64, **kwargs)
    149     from matplotlib.backend_bases import FigureCanvasBase
    150     FigureCanvasBase(fig)
--> 152 fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
    153 data = bytes_io.getvalue()
    154 if fmt == 'svg':

File c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py:2193, in FigureCanvasBase.print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, bbox_inches, pad_inches, bbox_extra_artists, backend, **kwargs)
   2189 try:
   2190     # _get_renderer may change the figure dpi (as vector formats
   2191     # force the figure dpi to 72), so we need to set it again here.
   2192     with cbook._setattr_cm(self.figure, dpi=dpi):
-> 2193         result = print_method(
   2194             filename,
   2195             facecolor=facecolor,
   2196             edgecolor=edgecolor,
   2197             orientation=orientation,
   2198             bbox_inches_restore=_bbox_inches_restore,
   2199             **kwargs)
   2200 finally:
   2201     if bbox_inches and restore_bbox:

File c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py:2043, in FigureCanvasBase._switch_canvas_and_return_print_method.<locals>.<lambda>(*args, **kwargs)
   2039     optional_kws = {  # Passed by print_figure for other renderers.
   2040         "dpi", "facecolor", "edgecolor", "orientation",
   2041         "bbox_inches_restore"}
   2042     skip = optional_kws - {*inspect.signature(meth).parameters}
-> 2043     print_method = functools.wraps(meth)(lambda *args, **kwargs: meth(
   2044         *args, **{k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if k not in skip}))
   2045 else:  # Let third-parties do as they see fit.
   2046     print_method = meth

File c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py:497, in FigureCanvasAgg.print_png(self, filename_or_obj, metadata, pil_kwargs)
    450 def print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *, metadata=None, pil_kwargs=None):
    451     """
    452     Write the figure to a PNG file.
    453 
   (...)
    495         *metadata*, including the default 'Software' key.
    496     """
--> 497     self._print_pil(filename_or_obj, "png", pil_kwargs, metadata)

File c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py:445, in FigureCanvasAgg._print_pil(self, filename_or_obj, fmt, pil_kwargs, metadata)
    440 def _print_pil(self, filename_or_obj, fmt, pil_kwargs, metadata=None):
    441     """
    442     Draw the canvas, then save it using `.image.imsave` (to which
    443     *pil_kwargs* and *metadata* are forwarded).
    444     """
--> 445     FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
    446     mpl.image.imsave(
    447         filename_or_obj, self.buffer_rgba(), format=fmt, origin="upper",
    448         dpi=self.figure.dpi, metadata=metadata, pil_kwargs=pil_kwargs)

File c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py:383, in FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
    381 def draw(self):
    382     # docstring inherited
--> 383     self.renderer = self.get_renderer()
    384     self.renderer.clear()
    385     # Acquire a lock on the shared font cache.

File c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py:398, in FigureCanvasAgg.get_renderer(self)
    396 reuse_renderer = (self._lastKey == key)
    397 if not reuse_renderer:
--> 398     self.renderer = RendererAgg(w, h, self.figure.dpi)
    399     self._lastKey = key
    400 return self.renderer

File c:\users\a\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py:70, in RendererAgg.__init__(self, width, height, dpi)
     68 self.width = width
     69 self.height = height
---> 70 self._renderer = _RendererAgg(int(width), int(height), dpi)
     71 self._filter_renderers = []
     73 self._update_methods()

ValueError: Image size of 79464x25555 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.
<Figure size 640x480 with 1 Axes>

Thank you in advance for help!

What do you mean by visualize? Does model.summary() resolve your issue?

@VardanGrigoryants by visualizing I mean https://i.ytimg.com/vi/L40sFs_-W_o/maxresdefault.jpg

So I guess model.summary() wouldn't work in this case

If you just want to get a summary of the model you can use model.summary().
But if you want to get something more than what you get from the summary, then you would have to use tools like Net2Vis and visualkeras.
There are a few more tools like the above, listed in this repo Tools-to-Design-or-Visualize-Architecture-of-Neural-Network


I don't believe there'd be any automated tool or library for that. The image you provided in the comment is most likely visualized manually using PowerPoint.

You can use torchsummary and get a summary.
Code
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torchsummary import summary

model = nn.Sequential()
model.add_module('conv1', nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=32, kernel_size=2, padding=1))
model.add_module('relu1', nn.ReLU())
model.add_module('pool1', nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2))
model.add_module('dropout1', nn.Dropout(p=0.4))

model.add_module('conv2', nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=2, padding=1))
model.add_module('relu2', nn.ReLU())
model.add_module('pool2', nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2))
model.add_module('dropout2', nn.Dropout(p=0.4))

model.add_module('conv3', nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=2, padding=1))
model.add_module('relu3', nn.ReLU())
model.add_module('pool3', nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2))
model.add_module('dropout3', nn.Dropout(p=0.4))

model.add_module('conv4', nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=256, kernel_size=2, padding=1))
model.add_module('relu4', nn.ReLU())

model.add_module('conv5', nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=512, kernel_size=3, padding=1))
model.add_module('relu5', nn.ReLU())


def get_output_shape(module, input, output):
    print(f"{module}: {output.shape}")


for layer in model:
    layer.register_forward_hook(get_output_shape)

dummy_input = torch.randn(1, 3, 224, 224)

output = model(dummy_input)

summary(model, (3, 224, 224))


Prints
Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)): torch.Size([1, 32, 225, 225])
ReLU(): torch.Size([1, 32, 225, 225])
MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False): torch.Size([1, 32, 112, 112])
Dropout(p=0.4, inplace=False): torch.Size([1, 32, 112, 112])
Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)): torch.Size([1, 64, 113, 113])
ReLU(): torch.Size([1, 64, 113, 113])
MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False): torch.Size([1, 64, 56, 56])
Dropout(p=0.4, inplace=False): torch.Size([1, 64, 56, 56])
Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)): torch.Size([1, 128, 57, 57])
ReLU(): torch.Size([1, 128, 57, 57])
MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False): torch.Size([1, 128, 28, 28])
Dropout(p=0.4, inplace=False): torch.Size([1, 128, 28, 28])
Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)): torch.Size([1, 256, 29, 29])
ReLU(): torch.Size([1, 256, 29, 29])
Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)): torch.Size([1, 512, 29, 29])
ReLU(): torch.Size([1, 512, 29, 29])
Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)): torch.Size([2, 32, 225, 225])
ReLU(): torch.Size([2, 32, 225, 225])
MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False): torch.Size([2, 32, 112, 112])
Dropout(p=0.4, inplace=False): torch.Size([2, 32, 112, 112])
Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)): torch.Size([2, 64, 113, 113])
ReLU(): torch.Size([2, 64, 113, 113])
MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False): torch.Size([2, 64, 56, 56])
Dropout(p=0.4, inplace=False): torch.Size([2, 64, 56, 56])
Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)): torch.Size([2, 128, 57, 57])
ReLU(): torch.Size([2, 128, 57, 57])
MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False): torch.Size([2, 128, 28, 28])
Dropout(p=0.4, inplace=False): torch.Size([2, 128, 28, 28])
Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)): torch.Size([2, 256, 29, 29])
ReLU(): torch.Size([2, 256, 29, 29])
Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)): torch.Size([2, 512, 29, 29])
ReLU(): torch.Size([2, 512, 29, 29])
----------------------------------------------------------------
        Layer (type)               Output Shape         Param #
================================================================
            Conv2d-1         [-1, 32, 225, 225]             416
              ReLU-2         [-1, 32, 225, 225]               0
         MaxPool2d-3         [-1, 32, 112, 112]               0
           Dropout-4         [-1, 32, 112, 112]               0
            Conv2d-5         [-1, 64, 113, 113]           8,256
              ReLU-6         [-1, 64, 113, 113]               0
         MaxPool2d-7           [-1, 64, 56, 56]               0
           Dropout-8           [-1, 64, 56, 56]               0
            Conv2d-9          [-1, 128, 57, 57]          32,896
             ReLU-10          [-1, 128, 57, 57]               0
        MaxPool2d-11          [-1, 128, 28, 28]               0
          Dropout-12          [-1, 128, 28, 28]               0
           Conv2d-13          [-1, 256, 29, 29]         131,328
             ReLU-14          [-1, 256, 29, 29]               0
           Conv2d-15          [-1, 512, 29, 29]       1,180,160
             ReLU-16          [-1, 512, 29, 29]               0
================================================================
Total params: 1,353,056
Trainable params: 1,353,056
Non-trainable params: 0
----------------------------------------------------------------
Input size (MB): 0.57
Forward/backward pass size (MB): 64.11
Params size (MB): 5.16
Estimated Total Size (MB): 69.84
----------------------------------------------------------------



Then, if you want to plot it, you could parse and code it using matplotlib, to make a CNN architecture.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def _arch(layers):
    plt.figure(figsize=(16, 10))

    for i, (l, _) in enumerate(layers):
        row = i // 4
        col = i % 4
        plt.text(col * 3, -row * 3, l, fontsize=10, ha='center')
        plt.gca().add_patch(plt.Rectangle((col * 3 - 1.5, -row * 3 - 1.5), 2.5, 2.5, edgecolor='black', facecolor='none'))

    plt.text(0, 0, 'Input\n\n', fontsize=10, ha='center')
    plt.text(9, 0, 'Output\n\n', fontsize=10, ha='center')

    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.title('CNN')
    plt.tight_layout()

    plt.show()


layers = [
    ('Conv2d(3, 32)', (32, 225, 225)),
    ('ReLU', (32, 225, 225)),
    ('MaxPool2d', (32, 112, 112)),
    ('Dropout', (32, 112, 112)),
    ('Conv2d(32, 64)', (64, 113, 113)),
    ('ReLU', (64, 113, 113)),
    ('MaxPool2d', (64, 56, 56)),
    ('Dropout', (64, 56, 56)),
    ('Conv2d(64, 128)', (128, 57, 57)),
    ('ReLU', (128, 57, 57)),
    ('MaxPool2d', (128, 28, 28)),
    ('Dropout', (128, 28, 28)),
    ('Conv2d(128, 256)', (256, 29, 29)),
    ('ReLU', (256, 29, 29)),
    ('Conv2d(256, 512)', (512, 29, 29)),
    ('ReLU', (512, 29, 29))
]

_arch(layers)



This is of course not complete, it is just an example:

